# How to write a major mode that does not open the file but provides a view on it

Tags: files, major-mode

I would like to write a major mode for inspecting netCDF files. These are binary files which can be multiple GB in size. So I don't want to open them in emacs.

The interaction that I have in mind is the following:

1. User opens netCDF file like any other file in emacs.
2. A command line program (`ncdump -h`) is executed on the file and the output is interpreted by emacs.

The problem is that there seems to be no way to stop emacs from actually opening the file.

Comment: Interesting problem. You won't be able to do this from the major mode because that runs too late: Emacs needs to open the file first because it can choose the major mode based on the file contents (e.g. `-*-my-mode-*-`). You'd need to hook earlier in `find-find-noselect`, perhaps at the place where there's now an exception for directories.

Comment: Do you just need a function that runs a process and sends the output to a particular buffer (with the filename being an argument that the user can choose)?  In what other way would you need a major-mode, since that normally implies operating on a particular buffer (e.g., what is the purpose of the major-mode, what does it do . . .)?  Here is the link to the manual describing various processes that can be started with Emacs:  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Asynchronous-Processes.html

Comment: A start would be to use `process-file` or `call-process` on such a file, using `ncdump -h` etc.

Comment: @lawlist Yes I could use a function that asks the user for a filename and then continue from there but I thought it would be a nicer user interface if users could treat the file like any other file. The major mode would be used to inspect or maybe even alter the binary file by calling different command line tools onto it.

Comment: Do you know the package [vlf](https://github.com/m00natic/vlfi) from elpa? I have the impression that this package does exactly do what you try to accomplish not with binary files but with text files. I think you can learn from that package how to do what you want. If you have a 64-bit emacs then the integer-limitations of emacs are also of no concern with this package. You can install the package via `M-x package-install`.

Comment: @Tobias No not really what I'm looking for. I just want to provide a view onto the metadata encoded in the binary file and not the binary file itself.

Comment: Maybe a simple key sequence would suffice  M-! ncdump -h filename RET

Comment: I recommend you take another look at @Tobias's suggestion.  Not because you want vlf's functionality, but because vlf needs the same functionality you need, so it's worth looking at how it does it.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty sure you can do something like this by making your file name "magic".  See [this part of the elisp reference manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Magic-File-Names.html).

Answer (score 1):

I use a package called `vorbiscomment`, which I now can't find at the URL in its header comment, and which doesn't appear in *ELPA or on EmacsWiki. Here's that non-functioning URL:

http://users-phys.au.dk/harder/

Anyway, it lets you edit the tag metadata for (binary) OGG Vorbis audio files, which sounds conceptually similar to what you want. It's really just a simple wrapper around command-line tools.

I've copied it to the following gist:

https://gist.github.com/PhilHudson/4fc8f38a5dc2b39f256feddb0014041c